# How to "squish" a range of numbers to the same spread between 0 and 1

Tags: data-transformation, range

So I have a range of numbers that I need to "squish" into values between 0 and 1 - where lowest value is zero and the highest is 1. I need preserve the ratio.

For instance. If I had these example arrays (all the same ratio between each other):

`0, 2000, 8000, 10000`

`0, 4000, 16000, 20000`

`0, 200000, 800000, 1000000`

I'm hoping to get back a result something like this for each of those individual arrays:

`0, 0.2, 0.8, 1`

Notice that the ratio between the numbers is preserved.

Is there a built in function somewhere (in `numpy`?) that does this for me?

Comment: Do you definitely need the smallest value to be $0$ and largest to be $1?$ Why? // Do you have a mix of positive and negative numbers? // What does it mean to have a ratio in the output space that involves the lowest number, now equal to zero?

Comment: > Do you definitely need the smallest value to be 0 and largest to be 1? Why?

Yes, since I want all the values "swished" to a value between 0 and 1 since a down stream dependency expects that range.

> What does it mean to have a ratio in the output space that involves the lowest number, now equal to zero

I don't know what that means, sorry. I'm just looking to squish a range of numbers down into values between 0 and 1. Same ratio. Is your question about handling 0?

Comment: Is zero always your smallest original value? If so, there is an easy solution.

Comment: Oh I see. No, zero won't always be the smallest number. For instance, for the array [500, 750, 1000] I would expect [0, 0.5, 1]

Comment: Then your task cannot be accomplished. Perhaps you can post a new question about the downstream analysis that requires the 0-1 range.

Comment: Remove dimension: xnew = (xold-xmin)/(xmax-xmin); fwiw you can map any range to between -1 and 1 with tanh, which is one of the reasons why they like it as a transfer function in NN's.

Answer (score 5):

You're asking for a function $f$, defined on some closed interval $\left[m, M\right]$, with values is $\left[0, 1\right]$, with the property that:

$$\frac{f(x)}{f(y)} = \frac{x}{y}$$

for all $x < y$ in said interval.

From this specification, we can derive a property the function must have. Fix $y$ to any non-zero value for which $f(y) \neq 0$, and let $x$ stay variable:

$$\frac{f(x)}{f(y)} = \frac{x}{y} \Rightarrow f(x) = \frac{f(y)}{y} x = \text{constant} \times x$$

So any such function must be of the form $f(x) = c x$. Bringing in the requirement that $f(m) = 0$:

$$
0 = f(m) = c m
$$

So either $c$ or $m$ must be zero. We can't have $c = 0$, since then everything collapses, so it must be the case that $m = 0$.

Therefore, such a function exists only when $m = 0$. In this case, such a function is easy to construct: $f(x) = \frac{x}{M}$.

Answer (score 2):

Your specifications are not entirely clear to me.
Maybe starting with `x` and ending with `y` or `z` will
do what you want. [Arithmetic and plots using R.]

```
set.seed(1234)
x = rexp(20, .001)
min(x); max(x)
[1] 6.581957
[1] 3052.458

y = x/max(x)
min(y); max(y)
[1] 0.002156281
[1] 1

z = (x - min(x))/(max(x)- min(x))
min(z); max(z)
[1] 0
[1] 1

par(mfrow=c(1,3))
 hist(x, prob=T, col="skyblue2"); rug(x)
 hist(y, prob=T, col="skyblue2"); rug(y)
 hist(z, prob=T, col="skyblue2"); rug(z)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]